# Mix Two Textures with Animation

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

I picked GLSL to help me with custom transition of cube textures created by Three.js Scene, Camera, Mesh and ShaderMaterial. I got the script working so 2 cube textures can mix into each other with 0.5 opacity, so I can see both mixed on top of each other.

```
<script>
uniforms = { opacity: {value: 1}, tCube0: {value: 'CubeTexture'}, tCube1: {value: 'CubeTexture'}, tFlip: {value: -1} }
</script>
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    uniform samplerCube tCube0;
    uniform samplerCube tCube1;
    uniform float tFlip;
    uniform float opacity;
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
    #include <common>
    void main() {
        vec4 tex0, tex1;
        tex0 = textureCube(tCube0, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPosition.x, vWorldPosition.yz ));
        tex1 = textureCube(tCube1, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPosition.x, vWorldPosition.yz ));
        gl_FragColor = mix(tex0, tex1, 0.5);
    }
</script>
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
    #include <common>
    void main() {
        vWorldPosition = transformDirection( position, modelMatrix );
        #include <begin_vertex>
        #include <project_vertex>
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to understand how to apply animation so `tCube0` blends into `tCube1` within a second time interval.

And secondly, I want this to happen on user action, say click of a button, so initially `tCube1` should not be known until user does action, and then  texture `tCube1` is set and `tCube0` animates into `tCube1`.

Comment: Good point, of course. But how to make it animate? It's a static blend.

Comment: Oh I see. So I would use JS to do something like `uniforms['texMix'].value = 0.0 ` and increment to 1? What is best practice to manage this animation?

Comment: @Vad IMHO, the simplies way in this case is to use Tween.js. Using it, you can set duration of transition.

Comment: @prisoner849 Are you suggesting Tween lib to animate `uniforms` or remove GLSL approach completely?

Comment: @Vad Yes, I'm saying about animation of `uniforms`.

Comment: Yes, I just tried and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Using Tween.js for a simple linear fade on ONE value is like killing an ant with a sledgehammer. `performance.now()` with a little algorithm would be largely sufficient...

Comment: @Sedenion Creativity is up to the topic starter :) "A little algorithm", which manages one value, is okay for a rough demo, when you need to show it for just one time. Devil comes when you need transition for several times (with different and non-regular intervals) or, for example, on mouse/keyboard events. In such cases, Tween.js is very helpful. So, I see no problem in using of stable frameworks instead of re-inventing a bicycle.

Comment: @prisoner849 the "problem" is that tween.js is 200 kilobytes of text parsed and compiled by the browser which in this case would be loaded to perform a simple 0-1 interpolation using 2-4 functions calls... while the "re-invention of bicycle" would be at max, 200 bytes of ASCII text without any function call except `performance.now()`. That's what we call "optimization", and it is a good practice, despite the fact everybody now have a quad-core 2.5Ghz with 4GB RAM.

Comment: And in addition, this is a good occasion to learn how to do a linear interpolation over time, whithin a loop (native behavior of WebGL)... which is not like escalating the Everest.

Comment: @Sedenion if you run it on GameBoy, then yes, 200kbytes counts (in addition to 500 kbytes of Three.min.js) ) Optimization? You have to care about it only when you really have issues with it ) In other cases it's just wasting of time ) But I don't insist. An advantage of using Tween.js is that you can set its easing not only as linear.

Comment: @prisoner849 my point is that, we don't load a 200k library to do roughly that: `var start=performance.now();` \ `fade = (performance.now()-start)/duration;`. You call this "wasting of time", i call this "common sense".

Comment: @Sedenion As I said, for a rough demo it's perfectly enough, but you don't stop, go on to convince me ) Out of curiousity, were did you get Tween.js of such size from? It's just 4kbytes (tween.min.js).

Comment: I found some "createjs" file, probably I made mistake here, i don't use tween.js and I admit I never use this kind of library... and I would certainely not for only one division and one subtraction, ond even not x10 with user interaction: I simply don't need `<-----this---->` to do `|that|`, so I avoid `<-----this---->` and simply did only `|that|` myself. I think we said enough, we both have two different way of thinking, that's it.

Comment: I agree with both of you and your different points do help. My project will involve a lot of visual manipulations so if I use tween, it won't be for just a few operations for sure :)